# CIN validation using cin.fail

Tags: c++, validation, cin

I am developing a small program that asks for 4 integers one after the other using `std::cin`. I am using a function to request the integers, and passing in the maximum value allowed as an argument. To check if the the value is an integer i use `std::cin.fail`. The code which calls the functions is shown below.

```
    cout << "Specify source number (1 - 1024)\n";
    source = validate(1024);
    cout << "Specify destination number (1 - 1024)\n";         // For all except data, the value is equal to the value returned by the validate function
    destination = validate(1024);                              // The maximum possible value is passed in as an argument in each of the cases.
    cout << "Specify type number (1 - 10)\n";                  // User  is prompted to enter the desired values.
    type = validate(10);
    cout << "Source port number (1 - 1024)\n";
    port = validate(1024);
```

and the validate function code is shown below.

```
int validate(int max) {

int value;                                  // Initialise variable to hold the value.

for (;;) {                                  // Loop forever until correct input is entered.
    cin >> value;

    if (cin.fail()) {                // If cin fails to receive a value matching the declared data type.
        cout << "Characters are not permitted.\n";          // Notify the user of error.
        cin.clear();                    // Clear the error flag within cin.
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');         // Ignore the newline character in the buffer to prevent an infinite loop.
        }
    else if (value > max || value == 0) {
        cout << "The value you have entered is not valid, please enter a number between 1 and " << max << "\n";
        cin.clear();                    // Clear the error flag within cin.
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');        // Ignore the newline character in the buffer to prevent an infinite loop.
    }
    else
        break;
    }
return value;                           // Return the validated value.
}
```

This works fine if the user enters just an integer, or just a letter, it validates as it should, the problem i am having is if a user enters for instance `34d` or `22p`. I get the error saying `characters are not permitted` but then it exits the function and moves onto the next request.

Tried rearranging and all sorts cant seem to solve it.
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to `ignore` the rest of the line even if you are successful:

```
int validate(int max) {

int value;                                  // Initialise variable to hold the value.

for (;;) {                                  // Loop forever until correct input is entered.
    cin >> value;

    if (cin.fail()) {                // If cin fails to receive a value matching the declared data type.
        cout << "Characters are not permitted.\n";          // Notify the user of error.
        cin.clear();                    // Clear the error flag within cin.
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');         // Ignore the newline character in the buffer to prevent an infinite loop.
        }
    else if (value > max || value == 0) {
        cout << "The value you have entered is not valid, please enter a number between 1 and " << max << "\n";
        cin.clear();                    // Clear the error flag within cin.
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');        // Ignore the newline character in the buffer to prevent an infinite loop.
    }
    else {
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');        // Ignore the newline character in            
        break;
    }
}
return value;                           // Return the validated value.
}
```

If you think this is too repetitive, you can do something like:

```
struct ignore_till_eol {
  ignore_till_eol(std::istream& cin): input(cin) {}
  ~ignore_till_eol() { input.clear(); input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); }
  std::istream& input;
};

int validate(int max_value) {
  for(;;) {
    ignore_till_eol ignore(cin);
    int v;
    if( cin >> v && 0 < v && v <= max_value ) return v;
    if( cin )
        cout << "Value is invalid, must be between 1 and " << max_value << "\n";
    else
        cout << "Invalid characters in input\n";
  }
}
```

or

```
int validate(int max_value) {
  for(;;) {
    ignore_till_eol ignore(cin);
    int v;
    if( !(cin >> v) )
        cout << "Invalid characters in input\n";
    else if( 0 < v && v <= max_value )
        return v;
    else
        cout << "Value is invalid, must be between 1 and " << max_value << "\n";
  }
}
```